# Fetch filtered tuples from group operation in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have some transaction data like

txn_id, receiver_userid, sender_userid, amount

1,1,2,50

2,1,2,100

3,1,2,500
4,5,3,100
5,5,3,200
6,5,3,300
7,6,2,200

8,6,1,200

Now I want to find all receiver users who received more than 2 transactions from same another user, I've started written my PIG job as

```
txnrecord = LOAD './txndata' USING PigStorage(',') AS (txn_id:int, receiver_userid:int, sender_userid:int, amount:int);
grptxn1 = GROUP txnrecord BY (receiver_userid, sender_userid);
txncount = FOREACH grptxn1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (receiver_userid, sender_userid), COUNT(txnrecord) as num_txns, SUM(txnrecord.amount) as total_sum;
txncount1 = FILTER txncount by num_txns > 2;
dump txncount1;
```

Above is giving me correct group aggregates but my additional requirements are

1) find aggregated group record and their associated set of tuples (individual txns), e.g - if my group aggregates says userid 1 received 3 transactions from userid 2, I need to have all three tuples stored in another data file.

2) group aggregates not matching > 2 transaction condition should be ignored (here last two records should be ignored)

3) I want to assign sequence to my group aggregates and same sequence should be used as link key in their associated transaction tuples (to identify these three transaction records are associated with particular group aggregate).

I am experimenting by using various functions but so far no luck.

Any help pointers are appreciated, Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can carry BAGs created by the GROUP BY, they contain all of the original columns, to check it do

```
DESCRIBE grptxn1;
```

To answer requirements 1 and 2:

```
txnrecord = LOAD './txndata' USING PigStorage(',') AS (txn_id:int, receiver_userid:int, sender_userid:int, amount:int);
grptxn1 = GROUP txnrecord BY (receiver_userid, sender_userid);
txncount = FOREACH grptxn1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (receiver_userid, sender_userid), 
txnrecord, -- carry bags through the filter
COUNT(txnrecord) as num_txns, SUM(txnrecord.amount) as total_sum ;
txncount1 = FILTER txncount by num_txns > 2;
tran_dump = FOREACH  txncount1 GENERATE FLATTEN(txnrecord);
STORE tran_dump INTO 'another data file';

txncount2 = FOREACH txncount1 GENERATE (receiver_userid, sender_userid, num_txns, total_sum);
dump txncount2;
```

Requirement 3 is not easy to do in MapReduce without making it really slow or using some networked ID broker. May be you would not need it as the FLATTEN(txnrecord) will dump all of the columns present in the input file.